# My whole completes the reverse

Tags: riddle, word, poetry

> Clip my left to complete
>   Clip my right to reverse
>   Clip both sides to make
>   My whole completes the reverse

Comment: too late to answer, great puzzle, reminds me of Riley puzzles...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The word is

> UNDONE

If you clip the left it makes:

> DONE, which means that something is completed

If you clip the right it makes:

> UNDO, which means that you reverse something that was done

And if you clip both sides it makes:

> DO, which is make something

And

> The word UNDONE is something that was already reversed

Comment: Congratulations on your first accepted answer, Matías!